# OpenGL texture generation

Tags: c, opengl, textures

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use OpenGL. I want to create a texture from a byte buffer.

For some reason, when I do it with `glTexImage2D`, it does not work (*the texture comes out blank*):

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             texwidth,
             texheight,
             0,
             GL_RGBA,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             bytes
             );
```

When I use `gluBuild2DMipmaps` it does work:

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                  3,
                  texwidth,
                  texheight,
                  GL_RGBA,
                  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  bytes
                  );
```

What is the difference between the two, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know "it does not work"? Does it render a black texture or do you get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`?

Comment: It's a blank texture (the shape is uniformly coloured).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it "works" with `gluBuild2DMipmaps` and not with `glTexImage2D` (texture is black, I guess), I would guess you have a mipmap based texture filter for the texture (which is also the default). Try calling

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);  //or maybe GL_NEAREST
```

Always remember that `glTexImage2D` only sets an image for the selected mipmap level (in your case level 0) and if you use a mipmap-based minification filter (a constant with `_MIPMAP_` in its name) the results of the texturing are only defined if you supply images to all mipmap levels (which `gluBuild2DMipmaps` does for you) or generate them automatically using either

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
```

before uplaoding the image or the newer

```
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

once it's uplaoded. The former requires OpenGL 1.4 and the latter requires FBO support, I think, and is also the non-deprectaed modern way to generate mipmaps. These two ways (especially the latter) are also prefered to the deprecated GLU functionality.